# Pesapal: Problem: parameter_rejected | Advice: unknown_error_occured> oauth_parameters_rejected | request_xml_data

Tags: wordpress, api, payment-gateway

I am including Pesapal payment gateway in wordpress for the first time but getting this error:
I have searched but unfortunately not finding the solution for this error.

Problem: parameter_rejected | Advice: unknown_error_occured> oauth_parameters_rejected | request_xml_data

```
pesapal_consumer_key = listingpro_options['pesapal_secrit_key'];
pesapal_consumer_secret = listingpro_options['pesapal_pubishable_key'];



$token = $params = NULL;
$consumer_key = $pesapal_consumer_key;   

$consumer_secret = $pesapal_consumer_secret;   

$signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
 $iframelink = 'http://demo.pesapal.com/api/PostPesapalDirectOrderV4';


global $plan_price, $post_id;    

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$useremail = $current_user->user_email;
$userDname = $current_user->display_name;

echo 'Plan Price: '.$_SESSION['price'];
echo 'Post ID: '.$_SESSION['post_id'];


//get form details
$amount = $_SESSION['price'];
$amount = number_format($amount, 2);//format amount to 2 decimal places
$desc = 'desc';
$type = 'MERCHANT'; //default value = MERCHANT
$reference = '1053';//unique order id of the transaction, generated
$first_name = $userDname; //[optional]
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; //[optional]
$email = $useremail;
//ONE of email or phonenumber is required by merchant
$phonenumber = '1122336655';    
$Currency = 'KES';   
$callback_url = 'http://test.com/serviceexpert/redirect.php'; //redirect url, the page that will handle the response from pesapal.
$post_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf8\"?><PesapalDirectOrderInfo xmlns:xsi=\" http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"
Amount=\"".$amount."\" Description=\"".$desc."\" Type=\"".$type."\" Reference=\"".$reference."\" FirstName=\"".$first_name."\" LastName=\"".$last_name."\" Email=\"".$email."\" PhoneNumber=\"".$phonenumber."\" Currency=\"".$Currency."\" xmlns=\"http://www.pesapal.com\" />";
$post_xml = htmlentities($post_xml);  
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $callback_url);  

$iframe_src = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token,"GET", $iframelink, $params);

$iframe_src->set_parameter("oauth_callback", $callback_url);
$iframe_src->set_parameter("pesapal_request_data", $post_xml);
$iframe_src->sign_request($signature_method, $consumer,$token); 

?>

<iframe src="<?php echo $iframe_src; ?>" width="100%" height="620px" scrolling="auto" frameBorder="0"><p>Unable to load the payment page</p> </iframe>
```

Comment: were you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably that you telephone/email  are not valid

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of paramaters that could result into this error.

For instance, if using `https://www.pesapal.com` instead of `http://www.pesapal.com`

Poorly structured xml code.
Construct the xml code as follows:*(Some attributes have been omitted)*

```php
$post_xml ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
    <PesapalDirectOrderInfo
        xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
        xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"
        xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"
        xmlns=\"http://www.pesapal.com\"
        Amount=\"$amount\"
        Description=\"$desc\" 
        Type=\"$type\"
        Reference=\"$reference\" 
        Email=\"$email\" 
        Currency=\"$currency\"          
/>";
```